# MongoDB : Missing the key _id in the item

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have been given some code to modify. It is a Node.js app using Mongoose to interact with a MongoDb instance. In Mongoose several schemas were already set up and I've added a few. Among those are these two schemas which break apart a previously existing schema (which was working fine with small data):

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var MapConvertedProjectSchema = new Schema(
{
    project_id : {
        type: String,
        default: ""
    },
    dataset_id : {
        type: String,
        default: ""
    },
    properties:{
        type: {},
        default: {}
    }
});

MapConvertedProjectSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    next();
});

mongoose.model('MapConvertedProject', MapConvertedProjectSchema);
```

and

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var MapConvertedLayerSchema = new Schema(
{
    parent_id: 
    {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
    },
    class: 
    {
        type: String,
        default: 'MapLayer',
        trim: true
    },
    properties: 
    {
        type: {},
        default: {}
    }
});


//Hook a pre save method to clean date
MapConvertedLayerSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    next();
});

mongoose.model('MapConvertedLayer', MapConvertedLayerSchema);
```

I use the MapConvertedLayer schema like so:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var LayerConverted = mongoose.model('MapConvertedLayer');
var newLayer = new LayerConverted();
//newLayer._id is automatically populated with a value
//... add other properties
newLayer.save(function(err)
{
    if(err)
    {
        //...
    }
});
```

This works without any issues that I can discern. However if I try similar code with MapConvertedProject I get an error:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var ProjectConverted = mongoose.model('MapConvertedProject');
var map_converted = new ProjectConverted();
//map_converted._id is undefined
//I tried adding the comment below to create an _id manually, but it didn't make a difference when I tried to save
//map_converted._id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId();
console.log("Project Converted ID: " + map_converted._id);
//... fill out the other properties on the schema
map_converted.save(function(err)
{
    if(err)
    {
        //...
    }
});
```

The save generates this error:

ValidationException: One or more parameter values were invalid: Missing the key _id in the item

Does anyone know what is causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. There was another place in the code that had a dynamoose model with the same name that was messing things up. I was able to remove all references to dynamoose since it doesn't appear to be used anymore and that cleared up this issue.